# How to solve java 2D array

Tags: java

i wrote the code correctly for 2D array hourglass problem.but it shows only one error.i did not know how to rectify it and also i dint know how it will work on negative numbers.how i can get 13 as output from my code.

Input (stdin)

1 1 1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 0 0 0

0 9 2 -4 -4 0

0 0 0 -2 0 0

0 0 -1 -2 -4 0

Your Output (stdout)
0

Expected Output

13

here is my code:

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows =sc.nextInt();
        int column = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] a = new int[rows][column];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<column;j++){
                a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                
            }
        }
        int sum=0,max=0;
        for(int i=0;i<rows-2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<column-2;j++){
                sum =(a[i][j]+a[i][j+1]+a[i][j+2]+a[i+1][j+1]+a[i+2][j]+a[i+2][j+1]+a[i+2][j+2]);
                if(sum>max){
                max = sum;
                }
            }
        }
     System.out.println(max);   
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In the `stdin` you haven't provided the `rows` and `columns` value as input. Your code works fine and gives the output `13`.

For this particular problem, your `stdin` should be:

```
6 6
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 9 2 -4 -4 0
0 0 0 -2 0 0
0 0 -1 -2 -4 0
```

Where the first line represents rows and columns. And will be assigned to:

```
int rows =sc.nextInt();
int column = sc.nextInt();
```

**So what was the problem in your code?**

Previously these were assigned `1` and `1` [the first two inputs] and took only `1` and `0` (the next two inputs) as the corresponding value. As a result, it couldn't satisfy the entry conditions in loop. hence the sum remained `0` and showed that as an output.

Comment: I've already said, your code works fine, just you need to add `6 6` as the first line of your stdin